# How can I show that $\sup_{t \geq 0}(B^*_t-\mu t^{r/2})=_{law} \sup_{v \geq 0}(\lambda B^*_{v}-\mu \lambda^rv^{r/2})$

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

I am trying to show that

$\sup_{t \geq 0}(B^*_t-\mu t^{r/2})=_{law} \sup_{v \geq 0}(\lambda B^*_{v}-\mu \lambda^rv^{r/2})$

i.e the above two random variables have the same distribution where $(B_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R_+}}$ is  a brownian motion and $B^*_t=\sup_{s \leq t} |B_s|$

I am stuck. How should I proceed? I was thinking of using the scaling property of brownian motion but I cannot write down a precise answer. Can someone help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that you use the scaling property, ie $ \tilde B_t = c B_{t/c^2} $ ($c>0$) is a Brownian motion. Try this with some generic $c$, and then you should be able to guess what $c$ should be (in terms of $\lambda$). Recall also that "$\sup_{t\ge0} \iff \sup_{t/c^2\ge0}$", as $c^2 > 0$.

If you're still stuck, I'll show you in the morning. (I'm in the UK, so it's late at night here!)

---

Putting in as I suggested, the RHS becomes
$$ \sup_{v\ge0} (\lambda c B^*_{v/c^2} - \mu \lambda^r v^{r/2})
= \sup_{V\ge0} (\lambda c B^*_V - \mu \lambda^r (c^2 V)^{r/2} )
= \sup_{V\ge0} (\lambda c B^*_V - \mu (\lambda c)^r V^{r/2}), $$
where $V = v/c^2$. So choose $c \lambda = 1$, ie $c = 1/\lambda$, and since $v$ and $V$ are just dummy variables, this gives you your solution.

I leave it as a (hopefully!) very straightforward exercise to show that the change of variables for $B$ also holds for $B^*$. If you just plug in the change of variables I've done in the first line, it should drop out very quickly. :)

Comment: Actually I  have been thinking about this problem for quite some time. I haven't had a real course on probability theory so get stuck sometimes. I think if I substitute $t=\lambda^2 v$ then $(\lambda B_v)_{v \in \mathbb{R}_+}$ is a B.m with variance t, but I somehow cannot control the $\mu t^{r/2}$ term . In other words I no clue as to write down a precise answer. I would be very grateful if you could give me a detailed answer . Thanks

Comment: I am reading a paper on Martingale inequalities for my thesis and they using this argument all the time, so it would be very helpful if I could understand precisely how it works

Comment: I've added in the details. Basically, all you had to do was remember to change both terms together when you do the change of variables. :)

Comment: Thank you  so much , I understand it completely. And i indeed managed the "straightforward exercise" to complete your solution.Good night and I am very grateful

Comment: That's no problem -- glad I could help. I'm always slightly worried about leaving bits that I think should be simple, because if you don't actually do it, then occasionally they turn out to be actually difficult! Glad you were able to do it though!

Comment: Also, +1 for the question -- a bit different to most of the BM questions I've seen on SE. :)

Comment: Thanks Sam actually I was working on a similar problem of proving equivalence o flaw using the scaling property of the b.m, turns out I am still stuck.