# $ \sup_{t \geq 0}\big( |B_t|-t^{r/2}\big) \text{ and } \sup_{t \geq 0}\big( \frac{|B_t|}{1+t^{r/2}}\big)^\rho$ have the same law?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $r>1$ and let $\rho$ be its  Holder's conjugate and I need to show that the following two random variables have the same law

$$ \sup_{t \geq 0}\big( |B_t|-t^{r/2}\big) \text{ and } \sup_{t \geq 0}\big( \frac{|B_t|}{1+t^{r/2}}\big)^\rho$$

I asked a very similar question in a previous thread

[How can I show that $\sup_{t \geq 0}(B^*_t-\mu t^{r/2})=_{law} \sup_{v \geq 0}(\lambda B^*_{v}-\mu \lambda^rv^{r/2})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472556/how-can-i-show-that-sup-t-geq-0b-t-mu-tr-2-law-sup-v-geq-0#1472563)

and despite having understood the solution and  struggling for a while  with this problem I am at a loss on how to pick the right scaling factor. Please do not give full details, just some kind of a hint on the scaling factor would be very helpful. Thank you